# Google Sheets: How to replace text in column header?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-query

I have a query like this `=QUERY(B2:C9; "select (C  * 100 / B) - 100")` in my Google Sheets. What is displayed as a column header is:

`difference(quotient(product(100.0()))100.0())`.

I want to put a human readable description there instead.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Note that if you want to eliminate the returned header entirely then you can `label (C*100/B)-100 ''`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26897291/503688).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`=QUERY(B2:C9;"select (C*100/B)-100 label (C*100/B)-100 'Value'")`

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Label

Comment: @Andrew the part following label has to match the select statement exactly. if you have `select sum(B) ... ` then your label has to be `label sum(B) 'labelname'`

Comment: @mix3d then why is this not working ? `"select I, sum(J) label I 'aaa', sum(J) 'bbb'"`

Comment: @stallingone if you are aggregating (sum), you require a `group by I`.

Comment: It doesn't work when the label references a dynamic column name, like `(C*100/B)-"&A1&" label ?? 'Value' '") ` .   `Col1` gives  error `LABEL_COL_NOT_IN_SELECT`, as it doesn't seem to be permitted when input range is not an array

Comment: @arno it should work if the label matches the select exactly: `(C*100/B)-"&A1&" label (C*100/B)-"&A1&" 'Value'"`

Comment: This answer is correct, but it still took me a while to get it correct so throwing my example here in case it helps anyone. Note that the label is the last part of my query ```=QUERY('Sprint Commitments Log'!C1:E42,"select C, sum(E) group by C label sum(E) 'Points'")``` -

Comment: It helped me greatly! Thx, @AdamL!

Comment: Basically correct, but the example is overly simple and void of any explanation, thus not adequatly demonstrating how the `lable` operation is suppose to be used, i.e. it works completely differently from `AS` with SQL queries and is not part of the `SELECT` statement. It's in fact a statement with which to list colum id/name transformations to apply to the endproduct of the query and there's a specific order in which all statements such as `select` `where` `limit` and `label` need to be applied in: 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses

Answer (score 25):

Remember there is a **trick** there.

**Working** example of the query:

```
"SELECT C, COUNT(C), AVG(G), AVG(E) GROUP BY C ORDER BY COUNT(C) DESC LABEL COUNT(C) 'My count' FORMAT AVG(G) '##0.00', AVG(E) '##0.00'"
```

**Not working** example of the query:

```
"SELECT C, COUNT(C) LABEL COUNT(C) 'My count', AVG(G), AVG(E) GROUP BY C ORDER BY COUNT(C) DESC FORMAT AVG(G) '##0.00', AVG(E) '##0.00'"
```

Also **not working** example of the query:

```
"SELECT C, COUNT(C), AVG(G), AVG(E) GROUP BY C ORDER BY COUNT(C) DESC FORMAT AVG(G) '##0.00', AVG(E) '##0.00' LABEL COUNT(C) 'My count'"
```

It works ONLY if it's placed in the correct order with other commands.

Comment: This was what I kept getting hung up on. For me I needed to add `label` commands between `group by` and `format`. Cheers!

Comment: That's a **trick**? I didn't know following the documentation was a **trick**. It clearly says ["The order of the clauses must be as follows: ..."](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses)

Answer (score 16):

It's counter-intuitive, but you must define your relabeled column **TWICE**; once in the "SQL" string, and then append the `label` clause to the end of the SQL string.

So, if you want to select A, B, C with "B" being labeled as "Foo", you would do this:

```
=QUERY(B2:C9;"select A, B, C   label B 'Foo' ")
```

If you're doing calculations, be careful to exactly match the SQL string definition and the label definition. For example:

```
=QUERY(B2:C9;"select A, B*2, C   label B*2 'Foo' ")
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Label

Comment: Isn't that the same as the answer from 5 years prior?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to rename more than one column, it uses one `LABEL` keyword, then separate the fields and their new name assignments using a comma.

```
"select B, D, D*C where D <> 0 label D 'Staff', D*C 'Cost'"
```