# Google SpreadSheet Query: Can I remove column header?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I'm doing this query at my google spreadsheet:

```
=QUERY(H4:L35;"select sum(L) where H='First Week'"; -1)
```

But it returns a little table with "sum" as header and result below it. What I want is just the result! How I remove header? Can I?

Comment: This seems more straight forward: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41797729/5316231

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Try this:

```
=QUERY(H4:L35,"select sum(L) where H='First Week' label sum(L) ''")
```

Comment: I just tested this in one of my sheets and it does remove the header from the returned results; this should be marked as the correct answer.  :)

Comment: Just a note, the `label` command looks like must to be at the end, even after any `order` command.

Comment: This is great and it works, but could anyone explain why the two single quote marks are needed at the end? What does that do from a syntax perspective?

Comment: The single quote replaces the sum header with empty space. Hope that explains your question!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I need to do the same with more than one column but I cannot achieve it! I expected this will work:

    
    =QUERY(H4:L35, "select sum(L), sum(H) where H='First Week' label sum(L) '' label sum(H) ''")

Comment: ``LABEL B 'Label1', C 'Label2'`` for multiple columns

Comment: NOTE: It's required that you does this "blank labeling" for every field being selected, or it won't work.

Comment: Another way of doing this **THAT YOU MIGHT THINK WOULD WORK** is to add 0 as the last parameter (the number of headers) to QUERY function. This would be an easier solution in the case of multiple columns. Comment below next answer from @dave-meindl explains SUM function adds headers. `QUERY(data, query, [headers])`
```headers - [ OPTIONAL ] - The number of header rows at the top of data. 
If omitted or set to -1, the value is guessed based on the content of data.
```
Explained here (same text as pop up help):
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en

Comment: This `query` function is so full of black magic... I wonder what sane user would intuitively think about this solution (which surprisingly work, thanks KRR!).

Answer (score 52):

`=QUERY(QUERY(A1:D, "SELECT *", 1), "SELECT * OFFSET 1", 0)`

The outer query: `"SELECT * OFFSET 1"` excludes the first row (the header).

The inner query explicitly specifies one row of headers (via the third argument supplied to `QUERY`), whilst the outer query specifies none.

Comment: A bit of explanation?

Comment: Why is the second `QUERY` necessary? Doesn't the "0" parameter drop the headers, so you can use it on the first `QUERY`, like this:  `QUERY('Form responses 3'!$A$2:$P$1017, "SELECT max(E),max(C), max(D) WHERE B='" & B14 & "' GROUP BY B LIMIT 1 ", 0)`

Comment: I believe `OFFSET 1` in the second query will drop the very first row of the returned dataset, not the headers in the first row.

Comment: This answer may be more verbose but it is also more robust and can be used without needing to duplicate column aggregation strings. It can even be used with `pivot`, which does not work with any other answer here.

Comment: The row that will be dropped via `OFFSET` is determined by the combination of values provided to the third parameter of the `QUERY` - I recommend setting them explicitly rather than relying on `-1` which asks the application to interpret the data.

Comment: Totally amazing answer

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this does not actually solve the specific challenge offered by the original poster, i.e. removing the headers that are automatically generated by QUERY when using aggregation functions such as SUM. When using SUM (or any other aggregation function), QUERY automatically creates a header row specifying the aggregation performed, e.g. "sum". It will do this even if you set headers to 0 and even if you apply the OFFSET 1 clause. The following formula still returns headers.
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:B,"SELECT A, SUM(B) GROUP BY A OFFSET 1",0)
The accepted answer solves this challenge.

Comment: If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail. Correct answer, but the outer query is a little too much for that. Using INDEX for that would make more sense. Or, obviously, the currently accepted answer, which is simpler

Comment: I just did a `=query(C6:Q300, "select sum(E), sum(F), sum(G), sum(H), sum(I), sum(J), sum(K), sum(L), sum(M), sum(N), sum(O), sum(P), sum(Q) where C matches 'targetdata' label 
sum(E) '', sum(F) '', sum(G) '', sum(H) '', sum(I) '', sum(J) '', sum(K) '', sum(L) '', sum(M) '', sum(N) '', sum(O) '', sum(P) '', sum(Q) '' ", 0)`. Hoped I'd seen your answer sooner ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
=INDEX(QUERY(H4:L35;"select sum(L) where H='First Week'"; -1),2,1)
```

This just parses the returned array and selects the 2nd record returned in the first column.

You can also do this with the filter function which is less compute intensive.

```
=SUM(FILTER(L4:L35, H4:H35 = "First Week"))
```

Comment: Thanks - with a complex expression being used to build the result, using the `INDEX()` approach is much cleaner than duplicating the expression in a `LABEL` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
=QUERY(H4:L35;"select sum(L) where H='First Week'"; -1)
```

Just make a SUM of the QUERY result - like this:

```
=SUM(QUERY(H4:L35;"select L where H='First Week'"))
```

With this solution, you can also calculate with the cells and then add everything up.

```
=SUM(QUERY(H4:L35;"select L*(S-R) where H='First Week'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a QUERY which is returning the top 3. I could not get this to work when returning multiple rows. I ended up just hiding the row with the formula and only the answers show now.

Answer (score 0):

For queries using pivot, try using INDEX to remove headers from the pivoted columns.

```
=INDEX(QUERY('Class hours'!A2:C11,
             "select sum(C) 
              where A = '"&A5&"' 
              group by A 
              pivot B"), 2)
```

Got the answer from this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63468791/5424088

Answer (score 0):

... or this

```
=QUERY(QUERY(H4:L35;"select sum(L) where H='First Week'"),"OFFSET 1",0)
```

This is more concise when ALL label classes are not wanted.

Note that 'select' and 'where' classes are not required in the second QUERY statement.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of labeling column names as blanks using `''`, you can omit all headers like this:

`=QUERY(H4:L35,"select sum(L) where H='First Week'", 0)`

Comment: Whist the accepted answer appears be more technically correct, this looks the simplest method to resolve the issue and easier to remember. Should be more love for this answer unless I have missed something

Comment: This answer does not remove the "sum" as a "header row".  It does tell the query command that there are no header rows to consider in the data being queried, but does not stop the query from adding an "unintended header" to the results table.

Answer (score -3):

See the format [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Label).

Example:

```
=QUERY(B4:C38,
   "SELECT C, sum(B) where C!='' group by C label C 'Member', sum(B) 'Sum'"
)
```

Comment: The example provided doesn't return a result without headers.