# Google sheets query to remove header not working with offset

Tags: google-sheets

Can't figure out why some of these queries work and some don't. Just trying to build a table of my own

```
=query(TRANSPOSE(ImportHtml(C7, "table",1)),"select * limit 1 offset 1")

=query(TRANSPOSE(ImportHtml(C2, "table",1)),"select * limit 1 offset 1")
```

Where `c2 = http://www.vitalmtb.com/product/compare/2819` and     `C7 = http://www.vitalmtb.com/product/compare/2775`

The ones not working bring back the row of headers, when I want to remove the headers and leave the data.

Answer (score 2):

The `query` formula has the third, optional parameter: the number of header rows. If it's not provided, a guess is made to what rows are headers (usually the top one is). In your first example, its guess is that there is 1 header row.

The header row is always a part of the array returned by `query`, which uses it to label the returned columns (unless you override that by providing different headers with `label`). This is why you can't get rid of it by changing offset: the offset determines with *data* rows to return; the header row is present regardless.

It you want to get rid of headers, set the third parameter to 0, so that the headers are treated as data. Then `offset` will offset past them:

```
=query(TRANSPOSE(ImportHtml(C2, "table", 1)), "select * limit 1 offset 1", 0)
```