# QUERY Google Sheet not remove headers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am using this formula:

```
=QUERY(gis_sources!$B$2:$L$3008;"SELECT SUM(J)/SUM(I) WHERE (B = 'i.bat' AND MONTH(C) = 7)")
```

But it gives me this header row:

[image]

How can I remove the header?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google SpreadSheet Query: Can I remove column header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867775/google-spreadsheet-query-can-i-remove-column-header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `label SUM(J)/SUM(I) ''` to the end of the query text to remove the header.

Add `label SUM(J)/SUM(I) 'your name'` to remove add your name as the header.

The text of query:

`"SELECT SUM(J)/SUM(I) WHERE (B = 'i.bat' AND MONTH(C) = 7) label SUM(J)/SUM(I) ''`

Comment: Thx! Oh wow, i add to the end same things, but without space - label SUM(J)/SUM(I)'' and its not working.