# How to stop upper() from being pulled through as part of Google Sheets QUERY?

Tags: select, google-sheets, array-formulas, uppercase, google-query-language

I'm unable to find a way of making sure that upper() is not pulled through when using the QUERY function on Google, specifically with SELECT.

I have an example below:

`=QUERY(countries, "SELECT UPPER(C)", 1)`

But this outputs upper() as one of the cells. In this case the first item of the column is Continent so this pulls through as "upper(Continent)

[Example Spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qcFNEnk420dJAM5JNedom3-ZqIwpHK4GHEPfLpMFDvc/edit?usp=sharing)

Does anyone know how to fix this so that upper() doesn't appear at all?

Comment: Could you please give some references on _where_ in the example spreadsheet the formula can be found? Also please show the input, the expected result, and current result.

Comment: It was highlighted in yellow bus as mentioned in my answer below, I managed to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867775/google-spreadsheet-query-can-i-remove-column-header)

Basically you need to label the column as nothing like so:

`=QUERY(countries, "SELECT UPPER(C) label UPPER(C) ''", 1)`

Hope this helps someone at some point as it took me a while to find!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(countries, "select upper(C)"), "offset 1", 0)
```

---

```
=QUERY(QUERY(countries, "select upper(C),upper(B)"), "offset 1", 0)
```

tho all you need is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER({C2:C, B2:B}))
```

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(UPPER({C2:C, B2:B}))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer player0, but I managed to fix this using "label"